# How do I get the keys of 'Properties' in this json file and make them column names in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to get the keys of the properties and make them column names. How do I do this please? The list just goes on and on so I am thinking a loop to get the keys as column names and the items as rows. How do I do this please?

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "facility_name": "HEALTH POST KAGBANG",
        "facility_type_display": "Health Post",
        "maternal_health_delivery_services": "TRUE",
        "emergency_transport": "TRUE",
        "skilled_birth_attendant": "FALSE",
        "num_chews_fulltime": 1,
        "phcn_electricity": "TRUE",
        "c_section_yn": "FALSE",
        "child_health_measles_immun_calc": "TRUE",
        "num_nurses_fulltime": 0,
        "num_nursemidwives_fulltime": 0,
        "num_doctors_fulltime": 0,
        "date_of_survey": "2014-02-25",
        "facility_id": "TSTEW",
        "community": "KAGBANG",
        "ward": "UKPE",
        "management": "public",
        "improved_water_supply": "FALSE",
        "improved_sanitation": "FALSE",
        "vaccines_fridge_freezer": "FALSE",
        "antenatal_care_yn": "TRUE",
        "family_planning_yn": "FALSE",
        "malaria_treatment_artemisinin": "TRUE",
        "sector": "health",
        "formhub_photo_id": "1393335750723.jpg",
        "gps": "6.54340807 9.08470312 218.8000030517578 5.0",
        "survey_id": "451a0efb-5fa6-4bad-93cd-7cf19eb50833",
        "unique_lga": "cross_river_obudu",
        "latitude": 6.54340807,
        "longitude": 9.08470312
      }
```

Comment: It doesn't appear the Json file is something that is easily mapped to a 2D table. You'll need to parse your API response first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)['features'].str['properties'].apply(pd.Series).T.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index': 'properties', 0 :'value'})
```

###### OUTPUT(top 10 rows):

```
                          properties                value
0                      facility_name  HEALTH POST KAGBANG
1              facility_type_display          Health Post
2  maternal_health_delivery_services                 TRUE
3                emergency_transport                 TRUE
4            skilled_birth_attendant                FALSE
5                 num_chews_fulltime                    1
6                   phcn_electricity                 TRUE
7                       c_section_yn                FALSE
8    child_health_measles_immun_calc                 TRUE
9                num_nurses_fulltime                    0
```

If you want to use properties as column names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)['features'].str['properties'].apply(pd.Series)
```

###### Output:

```
print(df.iloc[:, :3]) # printing 3 columns.
```

```
         facility_name facility_type_display maternal_health_delivery_services
0  HEALTH POST KAGBANG           Health Post                              TRUE
```